# Modules not found in Python packages

Tags: python-3.x, release, salib

I am having a problem importing specific modules in the most recent version—specifically the SALib python package (v`1.4.7`). I can see the files in the official repo, but they are not in my local environment nor in the released package's content.
The modules are `discrepancy` and `rsa`, and they can be found in the official repo:

- https://github.com/SALib/SALib/blob/main/src/SALib/analyze/discrepancy.py
- https://github.com/SALib/SALib/blob/main/src/SALib/analyze/rsa.py

So, I have cloned the repo to use it directly in my folder, but I am trying to figure out what is happening here. I can't see if it is a choice of the devs or something else. Is there any way to check this kind of issue?

---

What I tried:

- Checked the release notes to confirm whether these modules were present.
- Looked through the SALib documentation for any notes on module availability in different versions.
- Cloned the SALib repository directly from GitHub to access these modules, as a temporary solution.
- Tried different Python versions, just to ensure.

What I expect:

- A general answer on how to proceed when I encounter this kind of problem hahaha maybe the best way to solve it is by contacting the devs.
- Any insights or suggestions on why these modules might be missing?

Comment: SaLib 1.4.7 don't include rsa and discrepancy. They can be found in the main branch but not in the v1.4.7 tags.